# Enable dtrace without sudo on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, sudo, dtrace

How do I enable users to use dtrace on Mac OS X.  I am trying to do the equivalent of strace on Linux, and I don't like running applications with elevated privileges.

**UPDATE**

Ok, the best I can tell.  The only way to keep a nefarious application from ruining the system by debugging it is to.

1. Attach to the process in a separate console
2. Use sudo twice

So that:

```
sudo dtruss sudo -u myusername potentially_harmful_app
```

I verified this with this short program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "effective euid " << geteuid() << "\n";
}
```

See this discussion for more info:

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6430877

Comment: Answered here - you basically sudo back to the user you want to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007868/how-can-get-dtrace-to-run-the-traced-command-with-non-root-priviledges

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore: `dtrace: failed to execute sudo: dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see my update above.  This is a bad security hole if I've ever seen one.  A proper implementation of dtruss should drop privileges of any program it invokes.  Having several users on a system, one of them would be bound to mess this up and allow a badly written program to trash things.

Answer (score 1):

chmod 4755 dtrace as root

any time you run the program will run with root privileges

Comment: Does that mean that the application being run in dtrace will have elevated privileges?  How would I enable an individual user, and not others?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have both.  dtrace requires root privileges to talk to the kernel, so it either has to run with root privs (setuid) or by root.

Comment: So I have to trust that the application I am running through dtruss(dtrace) isn't going to harm my system?

Comment: How many users do you have on this box (is it os-x server or something?) and why are they running dtrace at all?  Anyway, if any of these responses answered your question, please reciprocate by voting appropriately. :-) thanks

Comment: See my update in the question area.  If I am trying to dtruss an application, I have to take unreasonable extra steps to make sure that the application I am trying to debug doesn't harm the system.  I filed a ticket with the Apple security team about dtruss needing to drop privileges before executing a program.